# how to add social share buttons on our webpage that share particular page we are recently in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, linkedin-api, facebook-sharer

I am trying to add share buttons on my webpage of various social medias. I put following code given by social medias

```
    For FB-Share
     <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?php echo "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" data-layout="button_count" data-size="small" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse">Share</a></div>
```

For linkedin share:

```
    <script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: en_US</script>
     <script type="IN/Share" data-url="<?php echo "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" data-counter="right"></script>
```

For twitter:

```
      <a href="https://twitter.com/" class="twitter-share-button" data-show-count="false">Follow</a><script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

But what happens here is if my current url/uri is "www.example.com/something" then facebook and linkdin shares only www.example.com . But twitter is working fine. Hoe can i make fb and linkedin to make it work like that? I want to share the page i am currently in. 
Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Encode your url in `urlencode`

```
<?php echo urlencode(your_url) ?>

href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo urlencode(your url) ?>"
```

Comment: you mean something like this? <script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: en_US</script>
<script type="IN/Share" data-url="<?php echo urlencode("http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);?>" data-counter="right"></script>

Comment: didn't happen bro :) . Is there any other methods?

Answer (score 0):

Use add to any plugin this is a simple plugin to share your website in social media

```js
<script async src="https://static.addtoany.com/menu/page.js"></script>
```

```html
<!-- AddToAny BEGIN -->
<div class="a2a_kit a2a_kit_size_32 a2a_default_style">
<a class="a2a_dd" href="https://www.addtoany.com/share"></a>
<a class="a2a_button_facebook"></a>
<a class="a2a_button_twitter"></a>
<a class="a2a_button_google_plus"></a>
<a class="a2a_button_linkedin"></a>
<a class="a2a_button_pinterest"></a>
</div>
```

For more details visit

> https://www.addtoany.com/buttons/for/website

Comment: are you share using this plugin is safe to use?